# Blender 2.8: face on edges get inverted when doing the beveling operation

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to bevel(Ctrl + B) an edge but it gets inverted

[image]

What have i done so far

1. Ive tried Ctrl+N to normalize object -> doesnt work
2. tried Merge vertices by distance -> doesnt work

please advise

Comment: to recalculate the normals select all and Shift N (not Ctrl N), maybe try that?

Comment: thanks it works :)